# Abaqus free free analysis?

Tags: modal-dialog, abaqus

I tried running a frequency model without any boundary condition It came out with error for unconnected region.
Is it possible to run free free analysis(with no boundary) in abaqus?

Comment: Abaqus Analysis User's Guide => Analysis Procedures, Solution, and Control => 6.3.5 Natural frequency extraction => Boundary conditions.
The answer is 'no'.

Answer (score 0):

abaqus could not run symmetry models.
one way to run free free analysis is to model the geometry symmetric and then fix the symmetry line with boundary condition.