# How does one model free-free boundary counditions in Abaqus?

Tags: abaqus

I was trying to model a free-free boundary conditions for a beam which is freely hanged using string on both ends (excuse the drawing):

[image]

However, I couldn't find any useful resources on doing so in Abaqus. My questions:

1. If I set the left (vibrator) end as a moving boundary (to simulate the vibrator) and right as simply supported, does the analysis still valid?
2. From this old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43240834/14298873), the author says to *"model the geometry symmetric and then fix the symmetry line with boundary condition"*, what is the *boundary condition* the author is talking about?
3. If there any other alternative solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the mechanical problem? What are you trying to model? From what I see on your sketch it will be a rigid body motion, so why do you need abaqus? Calculate it analytically